# how to Define a scope and let it sgow in the views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

hello please i have a model student, which have a field call admission_end:date i want to define a scope to help me get all student who's admission as ended that particular day it try this but my issue is how to make it show my views

this is the scope i defined

```
attr_accessible :address, :address, :admission_ends, :certificate, :country, :date_of_birth, :diploma_id, :email, :first_name, :full_name, :gender, :how_did_you_hear_about_us, :lg_area, :middle_name, :other, :relationship_with_applicant, :state_of_origin, :surname, :telephone_number, :telephone_number, :title, :title, :image, :amount_deposit, :balance, :full_payment, :next_payment, :part_payment, :programme,  :mode_of_payment
   belongs_to :admin
   mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

  belongs_to :diploma
  belongs_to  :payment
   scope :admission_due, -> { where("students.admission_ends >= ?", Date.today) }
```

Comment: r u trying to find the records for students who's admission as ended that particular day and sending the hash to views ?

Comment: You can get all students with that scope and write it in controller method as
@students = Student.admission_due

Comment: Debadatt are your sure the scope i define above is correct?

Comment: If you are finding in a particualar  day then this can
scope :admission_due, -> { where("admission_ends = ?", Date.today)}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define scope using lambda or proc because Rails 4 won't allow scope such scopes.

you can pass end day like this

```
scope :admission_due, lambda { |end_date| where("admission_ends >= ?", end_date) }
```

In view

```
Student.admission_due(Date.today)
```

Comment: thank you but i really want to knw what end_date his and how do i loop all the student through the views with Student.admission_due(Date.today)

Comment: sorry your question is quite unclear . Student.admission_due(Date.today) will give you a array of all students whose admission_ends is >= Date.today

Comment: my question right now is how do i loop that  in to the views i mean Student.admission_due(Date.today)

Comment: Ideally you should load your data in controller something like students = Student.admission_due(Date.today)   and then in your view use students.each do |student| <%= student.name %> end. Use instance variable for students.